# Create new-service with multiple dependencies from powershell

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Background: I have a custom task for TFS 2015 Build/Release to create a new windows service using powershell

```
New-Service -BinaryPathName $servicePath -Name $serviceName -Credential $cred -Description $description -DependsOn $dependsOn -DisplayName $friendlyName -StartupType $startupType
```

This works perfectly fine with a single dependency using the -DependsOn argument. The problem is one of my services has two dependencies. The [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849830.aspx) documentation states to use a comma separated list of dependencies. I've tried this with no luck. The service gets created but the dependencies are missing and the service fails to start. I have verified that the task is passing the values to the powershell script as expected. I'm passing -DependsOn MSMQ,MSDTC

I've tried passing it as a quoted string, which fails. I can pass the dependencies singularly and that works just fine.

My question is simply, how can I pass multiple dependencies to the New-Service powershell command from a TFS Build Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849830.aspx), `-DependsOn` is a string array, so pass it as a string array, namely:

```
-DependsOn ("MSMQ","MSDTC")
```

Comment: This gets me the multiple dependencies as expected. Thank you. I knew it was going to be something stupid simple I was missing.